# Collection library from Spark as separate project with fast HashMap

Tags: java, apache-spark

I've [read this blog](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/04/28/project-tungsten-bringing-spark-closer-to-bare-metal.html) and the following statement caught my attention

> The new hash table supports over 1 million aggregation operations per second in a single thread, about 2X the throughput of java.util.HashMap.

Is this class available as separate library or can someone point me to the class used?

(couldn't find it [at github](https://github.com/apache/spark))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer BytesToBytesMap.java at https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/apache/spark/unsafe/map/BytesToBytesMap.java.

You can also get some details in slides and videos at https://spark-summit.org/2015/events/deep-dive-into-project-tungsten-bringing-spark-closer-to-bare-metal/

Comment: Thanks & Nice, will look into it!